# Finding the length of a line segment along a line based on a vector force

Tags: geometry

I have line segment $AB$ and I would like to find the distance of $BZ$ based on an arbitrary line $CD$ (see below for a drawing). $CD$ could be going in any direction or angle.

I am at a loss as to how to find the distance along this line. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: You want to find a certain distance $BZ$, but it is not clear what you expect the answer to be (in terms of what?)  For example, you would need to provide some more angles and/or distances.  Else, any two intersecting lines would fit your figure, including examples with different $BZ$ values.  You might also want to show your efforts to solve the problem.

Comment: Ah sorry about that. This is an XY plain with 0,0 being the top left corner. If lets say for example A is (10,100) B is (50,10) and C is (0,0) and D is (0,3). Does that clarify it a little? I'm a bit of a noob with this kind of math.

Comment: Your figure does not show any point $C$ or $D$, yet seems to indicate a line "CD" that ends at point $B$ and starts at some unknown point. I do not know what is mean by "top left corner." If you know the coordinates of $C$ and $D$, then you can use hte Pythagorean theorem to find their distance, regardless of other points or lines.